# Рендеринг графиков Visualizer в Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ajax, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин Visualizer: Tables and Charts for WordPress, который нормально работает на сайте. Но недавно решил попробовать сделать бесконечную загрузку постов через ajax и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Графики которые находятся в постах загруженных с помощью ajax не отображаются на странице контейнер графика пустой. Сам контейнер заполняется через js на сколько я понял, а на момент создания DOM там нет этих новых графиков, которые появляются позже. Недельное общение с тех поддержкой пока не дает результатов (сложности перевода). Они не понимают или не хотят понимать почему это происходит.
Вот ajax запрос

```
function ajaxLoadPost (entries, observer) {
    let entry = entries[0],
    elem = entry.target,
    parent = elem.closest('#page'),
    link = parent.getAttribute('data-url');
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {         
        $.ajax({
            url:myajax.url,
            data:{
                action: 'singlescroll',
                nonce_code: myajax.nonce,
                link: link,
            },
            type:'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                wait_load = '<div class="wait_load"><span>Загружаю</span></div>';
                parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', wait_load);
            },
            success:function(data){
                if(data) {
                    document.querySelector('.wait-section').remove();
                    parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', data);
                }
                
            }
        });
        observer.unobserve(elem);
    }
}
```

А это php функция

```
function single_load_scroll(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'myajax-nonce', 'nonce_code' );
    if (isset($_POST['link'])) {
        $link = $_POST['link'];
        $postID = intval(url_to_postid( $link ));
        global $post;
        $post = get_post($postID);  
        $prev_post = get_previous_post(true);
        query_posts( 'p='.$prev_post->ID );
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            get_template_part('ajax-single');
        }
    }
    die;
}
```

Может кто то знает этот плагин и хотя бы даст направление в которое можно копать, буду признателен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Функция `get_previous_post()` не работает вне [главного цикла WordPress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_119/the-loop.html).

Comment: Где тут https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post/ написано что она не работает вне главного цикла? Там написано что она вернет null без глобальной $post, которая как раз установлена, поэтому в той реализации которую я представил все нормально работает, возвращается предыдущий пост как и положено.

Comment: В код функции посмотрите и поймете

Comment: Я спорить не буду, да и вопрос вообще не про это. Но данная функция в данном конкретном случае работает как ожидается, я сравнивал ее работу в главном цикле в single.php и тут, результат одинаковый. Проблема у нее только одна, если пост прикреплен к более чем одной рубрике, начинаются проблемы, но они начинаются везде и в главном цикле тоже. Позже придется свою функцию написать что бы исправить это, но сейчас для теста все работает нормально, если не считать одного плагина.